# How to call stored procedure in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.net Entity Framework. So I need to call a stored procedure and want to set a data to DateSet.

This is my function

```
public DataSet SearchEmployee(string name, string dep)
{
    db.f_t_PEOPLE_SearchEmployee(name, dep);

    return  db.f_t_PEOPLE_SearchEmployee(name, dep);
}
```

but there is error and it says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.DataSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The whole point of EF is that you don't need to use the old crappy `DataSet` stuff anymore..... EF works hard to convert relational rows and columns into **.NET objects** - like a `Person` or something. So your stored procedure will return a single `Person` or a `List<Person>` - not a DataSet.....

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is a ORM. This means that EF maps the data retrieved from BD to classes (objects) wich represents your business entities. I dont know if with some arcane voodoo programming haks you can read a datatable from a SP mapped by EF but what I am sure is that you shouldn't do it. EF was building to avoid DataTables and DataSets.